# Filezilla FTP Error 425

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Error 425.

I have read the top 10 answers here on this subject, some of them have an accepted answer, however none of them seem to help me resolve this issue.

I have done the following things:

- Set listening ports in FileZilla to 666(instead of 21) and 990 (default for tls)
- Set a custom port range for use in filezilla to 50000-51000
- Made an incoming/outgoing exception in windows firewall for filezilla server
- Forwarded all of these ports in my router

When testing my FTP via http://ftptest.net it seems that FileZilla uses a port within the range i defined & forwarded:

> 227 Entering Passive Mode (XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,197,116)
>
> 197*256+116=50548

And yet still i get the following error:

> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"

I have been researching this issue for days and i have no clue how to fix this.

two points that might be important:

- The FTP works from within my LAN, i only get this error from outside connections
- I Have another FTP defined in my router's firmware and it works fine for LAN/Samba/Internet connections.

If you need any more details please ask away.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT no change

Comment: When on the outside world, explain what it hops across to get to the server in brief and general if you could once it comes into the Internet connection on your side. So does it go from ISP router to a firewall appliance and then to another router or with no FW appliance and just straight from ISP router to another router with the port forward rules, or what exactly? Maybe I'm asking for too much but it sounds like something is not letting the data channel ports to the server after the communication stuff is established so help me visualize that in general and brief.

Comment: Oh, and I assume when you opened port `989` you tried an active connection rather than a passive?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT nope i tried only passive, but i retried now with active and still doesnt work, different error this time. Km mot near the server to give you the exact error but on the client its not a listing problem now with active.

Comment: The path is FileZilla on my computer -> Windows Firewall -> My Router -> ISP stuff -> Internet. Thats the general hops. On isp side i dont believe there is a block because as i wrote in the question, my router's ftp works fine. I also tried disabling windows firewall to no avail.

Comment: Do you use encrypted connection (FTPS) when connecting to FileZilla server and/or when connecting to router FTP?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i tried both on FileZilla, and they both work from LAN but not internet. in the router i tried insecure, i dont remember if it had a secure option.

Comment: Also i want to add that i check if my ports are open using a port checker tool and they are all open.

Comment: You might show screen shots of the port forwarding rules and maybe tell the make and model of the router you are using. At least tell the make and model of the router that has the port forwarding rules setup if nothing else I suppose.